# iframe is being greedy and prevents anything from appering in front of it

Tags: jquery, html, iframe

I've got an app which uses an iframe in a portion of a page, for displaying folder contents from a fileshare. Works great, except, any time a jQuery pop-up window or select menu overlaps this iframe, the iframe always appears on top, hiding the content from the parent page which I want to appear over the iframe.

I've messed around with applying z-indexes to the elements, but am just not winning the war. I've googled in vain, and am wondering if somebody out there in stackoverflow-land has a trick for getting an iframe to allow content on the containing pageto overlap it.

Comment: Is this happening in internet explorer?

Comment: @ Alan M: Does that mean you don't experience this issue in IE6 at all and only in IE7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say without any code - but have you had a look at using [the jquery bgiframe plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/bgiframe)

Comment: I did look at the bgiframe plugin, but it's only for IE6, at least that's what it says. I'll toss it in anyway and report back.